# Set class to next column if previous column has rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table as:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var span = 1;
  var prevTD = "";
  var prevTDVal = "";
  $("#table tr td:first-child").each(function () {
    $("#table tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function () {
      if (span > 1) {
        $(this).addClass('color');
      }
    });
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.text();
    if (value === prevTDVal) {
      span++;
      if (prevTD != "") {
        prevTD.attr("rowspan", span);
        $this.remove();
      }
    } else {
      prevTD = $this;
      prevTDVal = value;
      span = 1;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.color {
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1" id="table">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>aslkda</td>
        <td>asdasd</td>
        <td>asasd</td>
        <td>adfasdas</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content1</td>
        <td>asfasdasd</td>
        <td>asfdasdas</td>
        <td>asfasdas</td>
        <td>asfasdasdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content1</td>
        <td>ff</td>
        <td>asff</td>
        <td>asfsdfs</td>
        <td>sfsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content2</td>
        <td>sfsdfs</td>
        <td>sdfsd</td>
        <td>sdfsdfsd</td>
        <td>sdfsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content2</td>
        <td>sfsdfsdf</td>
        <td>sdfdfsd</td>
        <td>sfsdfsd</td>
        <td>fkfke</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content2</td>
        <td>sfsdf</td>
        <td>asfsdf</td>
        <td>djjdod</td>
        <td>ikowefk</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>kfjsdkvn</td>
        <td>,xsnv</td>
        <td>ksfhjsdf</td>
        <td>sdkvjsdkv</td>
        <td>sdkfhsdk</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

If 1st column of table has same content then I need to assign rowspan, which is working perfectly, but I need to assign a class to next column but only if `rowspan > 1`, I have tried but it assigns classes to 3rd row too. I copied rowspan code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28359469/12061795). I tried to stop propagation too that didn't help.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient refactoring of your overall strategy to be found, but this cleans up the third column issue:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let prevCell;
    let prevCellVal = '';
    let rowSpan = 1;

    $("#table tr").each(function() {
        let row = $(this);
        let firstCell = row.find('td:first-child');
        let firstCellVal = firstCell.text();

        if (firstCellVal === prevCellVal) {
            rowSpan++;

            if (prevCell) {
                prevCell.attr("rowspan", rowSpan);
                row.addClass('grouped');
                row.prev('tr:not(.grouped)')
                    .find('td:nth-child(2)')
                    .addClass('color');
                firstCell.remove();
            }
        } else {
            prevCell = firstCell;
            prevCellVal = firstCellVal;
            rowSpan = 1;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
.grouped td:first-child, .color {
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1" id="table">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>aslkda</td>
        <td>asdasd</td>
        <td>asasd</td>
        <td>adfasdas</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content1</td>
        <td>asfasdasd</td>
        <td>asfdasdas</td>
        <td>asfasdas</td>
        <td>asfasdasdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content1</td>
        <td>ff</td>
        <td>asff</td>
        <td>asfsdfs</td>
        <td>sfsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content2</td>
        <td>sfsdfs</td>
        <td>sdfsd</td>
        <td>sdfsdfsd</td>
        <td>sdfsdfsdf</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content2</td>
        <td>sfsdfsdf</td>
        <td>sdfdfsd</td>
        <td>sfsdfsd</td>
        <td>fkfke</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>content2</td>
        <td>sfsdf</td>
        <td>asfsdf</td>
        <td>djjdod</td>
        <td>ikowefk</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>kfjsdkvn</td>
        <td>,xsnv</td>
        <td>ksfhjsdf</td>
        <td>sdkvjsdkv</td>
        <td>sdkfhsdk</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/3yj8mu7q/)

Comment: Close enouh, look when content1 or content2 has rowspan == 1, don't show color just show it when it's greater than 1

Comment: Check, I have edited my snippet. now the second column has colors that what I need.

Comment: I need you to be more clear in your English. What exactly is incorrect about my results?

Comment: Your result is close enough, please see my result now, and compare your second column and my second column. My 2nd columns has color where the 1st column rowspan > 1 but your 2nd column has color where there is a rowspan.