# Make rowspan when data has same value in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have some data in mysql database, some of them are have same value.

[image: I have some data in mysql database, some of them are have same value.]

I already show it in my program:

[image: I already show it in my program:]

But it is possible to make rowspan like this?

[image: But is it possible to make rowspan like this?]

this is my code.

```
<tbody class="table-bordered">

    <?php $i = 1;
    foreach ($altrankq1 as $alt) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><?= $i; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?= $alt['kode_alternatif']; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?= round(($alt['nilai_Q1']), 4);  ?></td>


        </tr>
    <?php $i++;
    endforeach; ?>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe u can check the 'nilai_q1' like this(?)

```
<tbody class="table-bordered">

    <?php $i = 1; $a = null;
    foreach ($altrankq1 as $alt) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
        <?php 
            $b = round(($alt['nilai_Q1']), 4);
            if($a === $b) {
                $i = $i - 1;
                echo $i;
            } else {
                echo $i;
            }
            $a = $b;
        ?>
        </td>
            <td class="text-center"><?= $alt['kode_alternatif']; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?= round(($alt['nilai_Q1']), 4);  ?></td>


        </tr>
    <?php $i++;
    endforeach; ?>

</tbody>
```

nb: not tested yet and isnt rowspan

or trying with jquery, i found this answer in stackoverflow [rowspan-table-if-values-is-the-same-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28359469/8979042)

Comment: it didn't work. i think because the $a is always null

Comment: @AkhmadAli [fine with me](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b15D),