# How can I make rowspan using javascript for my table which has data from sql in Zend Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGxVk.png)

What I want is in this case there are 2 times Demo is being printed, if this column has same name then it should be rowspan. My data is bein fetched from sql and I have displayed on webpage using populate method and forEach(). This is my code.

```
function populateSubjectData(subjectDetail){
let table = `<form id="addExamSubjectForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="javascript:;" autocomplete="off">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="addExamSubject">`;
let header = `<tr>
                <th>Sr. No.</th>
                <th>Subject Name</th>
                <th>Sub Subject Name</th>
                </tr>`;

let body = "";

subjectDetail.forEach(function(subjectDetailObj, key){
  
 if(key == 0){
    console.log("1");
    
  }
  var prev = key;
  console.log(prev);
  var curr = key+1;
  console.log(curr);
  if(subjectDetail[prev].name === subjectDetail[curr].name){
    console.log("error");
      
    }
  else{
    console.log(subjectDetail[curr].name);
  }
  body +=`<tr>
              <td>${key + 1}</td>
              <td>${subjectDetailObj.name}</td>
              <td>${subjectDetailObj.subSubjectName}</td>
              
          </tr>`;
          
          
});
$('#subjectTable').html(table + header + body);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

my suggest is to :

1. structure the fetched data in the server side by grouping them
   by columns name, so you will get some thing like that :

```html
PARENT 1
  |_CHILD1
  |_CHILD2
PARENT 2
  |_CHILD1
  |_CHILD2
  |_CHILD3
```

2. in the client side ( javascript ) by knowing the number of childs
   in the current object you can make a `rowspan` in case it has more
   than one CHILD or not.

Hope that can be helpful for you.

Comment: In server side, I can not do any modifications because I'm not allowed to do it

And in client side, the number of Child will be unpredictable, sometimes it may have 1 or 2 or 3 or none at all.

I have even tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/28359469/14065006 this solution but didn't worked in me probably because I'm fetching my data from sql

Comment: ok in that case you can re-make the structure in client side using the map reduce arrays function , could you put and example of the data structure that you get from the server side ?